# DRAM (main memory) frequency is not fixed?

Tags: memory, clockspeed

I have a question regarding the DRAM (main memory) frequency.

DDR4-2666 DIMM frequency that is used by my machine is configured to be 2666 MHz (I checked with `lshw -short -C memory` command). As the device is Double Data Rate, I assume that the expected frequency, when measured, should be around 1333 MHz.

I read in various papers that DRAM frequency does not scale (up or down) and once it is configured in BIOS, it is global to the system. Unlike the CPU, which can be set in power save mode and run in significantly lower frequency in idle state. But again, by my understanding, this is not the case for DRAM.

However, I measured the memory frequency with `Processor Counter Monitor` [(PCM)](https://github.com/opcm/pcm?fbclid=IwAR2y-lEdyasJuBnGc5wALGMmoVqiJ04rLfqDWQUkJMyQHyUd6Ia3Eeu4jBw) tool. When the DRAM main memory is accessed, I indeed get `DRAMClocks` (representing memory frequency) around 1333 MHz. However, if the memory is idle, the results can be as low as just several tens of MHz (e.g. 46.8 MHz)

Therefore, I was wondering if such behavior of the DRAM main memory frequency is documented somewhere. Is it normal that it fluctuates depending on the memory state (idle or not)? Is this configurable?

Experimental environment is linux debian machine, 5.4 kernel version, Intel Xeon Gold 6130 Processor.

I found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/469182/is-it-normal-that-dram-frequency-changes-frequently), however the fluctuation there is way smaller compared to what I get, and can't be explained the same way.

Comment: Could be due to power saving and the CPU memory controller going to sleep for brief periods and so reporting its own clock.

Comment: @Mokubai but DRAMClocks is supposed to report about memory frequency, I asked at their git repository

Comment: Might be relevant:  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/reference/energy-analysis-metrics-reference/dram-self-refresh.html

Comment: The DRAM frequency is defined as what percentage bits are being transferred per second on one data line. It seems logical that when the idle CPU decreases its own frequency, so will change the DRAM frequency (or at least the measured frequency).

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, I have read about DRAM power down modes, Self Refresh included. This PCM tool also reports, more or less when DRAM is in power down mode (CKE off residency), but I think this is different characteristics. Even with my evaluation, actively accessed DRAM, I have two socket machine and the memory of the socket which is not accessed, stays in power down mode, but it's frequency still increases to 1333 MHz rather than staying within 46.8 MHz.

Comment: @harrymc I agree that this makes sense. It is just that when I read papers, it was stated that memory frequency fluctuation is not used to saver power, so it stays same. That is why I was wondering if there was some "documented" information that memory frequency has similar behavior as cpu frequency.